# Get Data from dialog box into EditText

Tags: android

I have a field named Select class with edit text view. Onclick of Edit text, i am opening dialog box with multiple selection. lets say i select 3 value and click OK. I want to show all the selected value in Edit text field with comma(,) seperator between two value.
I stuck here. Pls help me.

Comment: It will be easier for experts to help you if you provide actual code snippets.